# Cloud Functions: Function worker crashed with exit code: 3

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

in Node.js command prompt

> Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 6.14.0 (x64) and
>   npm.

run

firebase functions:shell

get error:

> i  functions: Preparing to emulate functions.
>
> error: FATAL ERROR: Zone Allocation failed - process out of memory
>
> error: Function worker crashed with exit code: 3
>
> error:  code=500, status=INTERNAL, message=Function worker crashed
>   with exit code: 3
>
> undefinedFATAL ERROR: Zone Allocation failed - process out of memory,
>   errors=[Function worker crashed with exit code: 3
>
> undefinedFATAL ERROR: Zone Allocation failed - process out of memory]
>
> error: FATAL ERROR: Zone Allocation failed - process out of memory
>
> error: Function worker crashed with exit code: 3
>
> !  functions: Error from emulator. [object Object]
>
> No functions emulated.

Answer (score 0):

Update: hmmm.... I just noticed that the message comes from the Cloud Functions shell. I don't think my steps below will solve the problem there, but will leave them up just in case.

---

As the error message says, your Cloud Functions fails because:

> process out of memory

You can either reduce the memory your code uses, or increase the memory that is available to your functions. Given that you didn't share details about the function itself, I'll focus on the second option.

To increase the memory available to your functions:

1. Go to the [Cloud Functions console](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/)
2. Select your function
3. Click <kbd>Edit</kbd>
4. Change the value in the "Memory allocated" dropdown
5. Click <kbd>Save</kbd>